# How to fix process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to run this project [phimp.me](https://github.com/fossasia/phimpme-android/).I have used **c++_static** as per the new document mentioned in android `supporting C++ library`, still it throws the same error.
I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, replacing `c++_static` with `c++_shared` but its throws the same error.
Also  I tried renaming the `OpenCV.mk` file to `OpenCVX86.mk` file as per one link.
I have rechecked and downloaded `NDK` and `CMake` from SDK Tools but its stuck with the same error.

> Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE := STATIC
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := nativeimageprocessing

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK \
                -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main_processing.cpp enhance.cpp filters.cpp colour_space.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lm -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

> Application.mk file

```
APP_STL := c++_static
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_PLATFORM := android-25
```

> Error

```
Build command failed.


Error while executing process C:\Users\satyasarathim\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\Workshop\phimpme-android-development\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\Workshop\phimpme-android-development\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-17 NDK_OUT=D:/Workshop/phimpme-android-development/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\Workshop\phimpme-android-development\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL c++_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
```

Comment: Finally solved by the help of this link.
https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/47#issuecomment-453721764.

It was really a problem with ndk-build.cmd file.

Comment: The "fix" in that thread didn't fix anything. That just stopped the ndk from running at all.

Comment: What version of the NDK are you using?

Comment: I am using NDK 19.0.

Answer (score 3):

Its work for me by this instruction:

Redirect to ndk directory and open ndk-build.cmd file and remove this line

%~dp0\build\ndk-build.cmd %*

really its work for me

of this link:
https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/47

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure how you got that error. I cloned the project and followed the instructions in the README. I got a lot of errors because the project is using an ancient gradle plugin, but those were easily fixed: https://github.com/fossasia/phimpme-android/pull/2684

However, even after dealing with most of those issues, it turns out the project still can't be built with NDK r18 or newer because the project contains prebuilt OpenCV libraries that are built against gnustl. gnustl and libc++ are not ABI compatible, so they cannot be used with libc++, which is the only option in r18+.

Your options for fixing that are:

1. Rebuild the OpenCV libraries against libc++.
2. Use NDK r17.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, use the 64-bit NDK instead of 32-bit - this worked for me (verified in r16b)