# How can I install Python packages on windows?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, package, wrapper

I'm trying to install [this](https://lesgourg.github.io/class_public/class.html) package on Windows 10. The instructions to install the Python wrapper are [these](https://github.com/lesgourg/class_public/wiki/Python-wrapper), but I'm encountering some problems. 
I followed the attached instructions using the Ubuntu shell available in the new Windows Terminal and the installation has been successful; however the Spyder IDE, installed with Anaconda, does not recognize the module. It is as if I've installed the package somewhere else.

Have you got any suggestions? As you can tell I'm quite new to this kind of operation.
Thank you so much.

Comment: It might not work if Spyder and Anaconda is installed under Windows 10 and your wrapper is installed under WSL Ubuntu. They can't really communicate with each other unless the programs explicitly support that. So try and install the wrapper under Windows 10 instead, with powershell.

Comment: Thanks. I tried installing `make` in the Powershell with [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) but I get the same error I wrote below:
`process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
Makefile:4: pipe: No error
cp python/setup.py python/autosetup.py
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cp python/setup.py python/autosetup.py, ...) failed.
make (e=2): Impossible to find the specified file.
make: *** [Makefile:176: classy] Error 2`
I guess I'm missing a small detail here...

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Just go to your anaconda prompt installed on your computer and do it from there. I hope it helps (:

Comment: Thanks. When using `make` from the anaconda prompt I get the following error, though:

`process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
Makefile:4: pipe: No error
cp python/setup.py python/autosetup.py
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cp python/setup.py python/autosetup.py, ...) failed.
make (e=2): Impossible to find specified file.
make: *** [Makefile:176: classy] Error 2`

Comment: Where is your makefile? You have to be sure you have the makefile, otherwise it will not work :)

Comment: It's quite odd. I'm sure I'm in the right folder, but both with the Powershell and in the Anaconda shell I'm now getting this message:
`process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
Makefile:4: pipe: No error
if ! [ -e /build ]; then mkdir /build ; mkdir /build/lib; fi;
[ unexpected.
make: *** [Makefile:8: .base] Error 255`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Of course you are running the Makefile, maybe this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54404007/how-to-fix-process-begin-createprocessnull-failed-error

Comment: Thanks but I don't really know how to apply this to my issue...